# How to version an API in Azure API Management using Azure Resource Manager

Tags: api, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

When creating a new API in an Azure API Management Service using the portal, you can specify whether you would like the API to be versioned. However, I can't find a way to replicate this when creating an API in the Management service using ARM. Is this not currently supported, or am I missing something?

I have tried creating a versioned API in the portal and comparing the created template to the template of a non-versioned API and can't see a difference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this through ARM scripts you'll need to create an ApiVersionSet resource first:

```
{
    "name": "[concat(variables('ManagementServiceName'), '/', variables('VersionSetName'))]",
    "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/api-version-sets",
    "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Api Description",
        "displayName": "Api Name",
        "versioningScheme": "Segment"
    }
}
```

Then update the `apiVersionSetId` property on the `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis` resource:

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
        "name": "[concat(variables('ManagementServiceName'), '/', variables('ApiName'))]",
        "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/api-version-sets', variables('ManagementServiceName'), variables('VersionSetName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "displayName": "string",
            "apiRevision": "1",
            "description": "",
            "serviceUrl": "string",
            "path": "string",
            "protocols": [
                "https"
            ],
            "isCurrent": true,
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "apiVersionName": "v1",
            "apiVersionDescription": "string",
            "apiVersionSetId": "[concat('/api-version-sets', variables('VersionSetName'))]"
        }
    }
```

Comment: due to some reason `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/api-version-sets` isn't being recognized inside template ?  Can someone check if still it's the same type?

Answer (score 0):

resource for the **api-version-sets**

```
              "name": "my-api-version-sets",
              "type": "api-version-sets",
              "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
              "properties": {
                "displayName": "Provider API",
                "versioningScheme": "Segment"
              },
              "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/', variables('apiManagementServiceName'))]"
              ]
```

Then other to **apis**

```
                "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
                "type": "apis",

                "properties": {
                    ....

                    "isCurrent": true,
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "apiVersionSetId": "/api-version-sets/my-api-version-sets"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the version on Azure ARM portal in path,header or as a query string.But the old azure API management portal not support in build versioning.Any way you can specify the versioning in Web API URL suffix.

Still if you have any issue kindly add some image and describe your issue.

[Azure ARM Portal (New APIM)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGynL.png)

[Azure APIM Portal (OLD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmzRH.png)

Thanks,
Infaaz

Comment: I down voted because the question was how to achieve it with ARM templates not with UI.